# Incompatible oAuth2 token requests between python oauth2 request and spring oauth2 server

Tags: python, django, spring, oauth

My python oauth2 client is attempting to fetch an access_token via [python requests](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib)

to a 3rd party using [spring oauth](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

via a token code.

```
 auth_session = OAuth2Session(
            self.configuration_store.client_id, redirect_uri=self.configuration_store.redirect_url)

 auth_session.fetch_token(
            self.configuration_store.token_url, client_secret=self.configuration_store.client_secret, code=code,
            headers=utils.generate_header(self.configuration_store.client_id, self.configuration_store.client_secret),
            **{"access_token": "TOKEN", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 3599, 'scope': 'bar read write'})
```

Using the same code against our local test server using [django oauth toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) implementation, the above code successfully retrieves a token. However, against the spring provider, returning a 401.

Furthermore, if I construct the request to the 3rd party manually using straight python requests, I can get success.

```
result = requests.post(self.configuration_store.token_url,
                                params = {'grant_type':'authorization_code', 'client_id': self.configuration_store.client_id, 'code':code, 'client_secret':self.configuration_store.client_secret, 'redirect_uri':self.configuration_store.redirect_url },
                       headers =utils.generate_header(self.configuration_store.client_id, self.configuration_store.client_secret), data={"access_token": "TOKEN","token_type": "bearer","expires_in": 3599,"scope": ["bar", "read", "write"]})
```

However the POST requests are completely different.

Working requests using `request.post...`

```
# Working
INFO 2016-11-28 08:19:15,303 connectionpool 50122 123145426345984 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): example.com
send: b'POST /authorization/oauth/token?redirect_uri=https://theredirecturl.com/login&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXX&code=XXXXXXX&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=clientid HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 85
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
Cache-Control: no-cache

scope=bar&scope=read&scope=write&token_type=bearer&access_token=TOKEN&expires_in=3599'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
'
```

Not working using oauth [python requests](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib)

```
INFO 2016-11-29 23:32:18,063 connectionpool 73412 123145511739392 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): example.com
send: b'POST /authorization/oauth/token/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 247
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*

grant_type=authorization_code&expires_in=3599&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&access_token=TOKEN&scope=bar+read+write&client_id=clientid&code=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://theredirecturl.com/login&token_type=bearer'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
'
```

The two requests have totally different bodies and it seems weird to me that oauth would put things like client_secret etc in the URL.

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated.